# Break long formula R documentation

Tags: r

I have a long formula that I need to break in the R documentation of a package or it trails off the right hand side of the page.  HEre's the formula in roxygen2 style:

```
#' \deqn{Cov(r_{ist}, r_{iuv})= [.5\rho_{ist}\rho_{iuv}(\rho_{isu}^2 + 
#' \rho_{isv}^2 + \rho_{itu}^2 + \rho_{itv}^2) + \rho_{isu}\rho_{itv}+ \newline 
#' \indent \rho_{isv}\rho_{itu}-(\rho_{ist}\rho_{isu}\rho_{isv} + 
#' \rho_{its}\rho_{itu}\rho_{itv}) + \rho_{ius}\rho_{iut}\rho_{iuv} + 
#' \rho_{ivs}\rho_{ivt}\rho_{ivu}]/n_i}
```

Notice I tried to use \new line and indent but this didn't work it still trails off the edge.

How can I break the formula and indent it?  Maybe indenting isn't appropriate (not sure on that).

Comment: I'm going to cross post this at r-help and link/report the response back here (if any).